# Openldap upgrade from 2.4 to 2.5

Tags: ldap, active-directory, openldap

we are using Openldap version Version: 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.10
how can I upgrade or migrate to 2.5?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. You have some problem, and you have concluded that migrating to OpenLDAP 2.5.x is the solution. However, it's a very difficult solution due to the way Debian-based systems are designed. It's a simple question with a very complex set of answers. Other solutions may be much easier for you. Back up and ask about the actual problem you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release, but an `rmadison` query makes it look like you're using `openldap | 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.10  | bionic-updates   | source`.  I see only one release which currently has 2.5.5 in the list; but maybe it's available via 3rd party sources (PPA) but you are using an older release which may reduce your odds a little.

Comment: thanks, @guiverc, I'm having an issue removing olcoverlay, got the info LDAP 2.5 version has the ability to remove those.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an excellent instructions how to find your old data from (automatic apt) backups, and how to manually migrate your data from 2.4 to 2.5 in an event of any error:

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/service-migrating-from-openldap-2-4-x-to-2-5-x/23807

Comment: Could you please put the steps from that link in your answer? Then, if the link breaks, your answer is still useful. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry it's too long. You really need to read the article :/ I'm looking forward for this link to to disappear anytime soon, since it's the official Ubuntu documentation on this very topic.